# More concise way of turning an array into an object with default values? (Lodash is available)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, say `["a","b","c"]`, and I want to turn this into an object which has the array values as keys and a default value that I can set. So if the default value is `true`, I'd like my output to be `{a:true, b:true, c:true}`.

Is there a more concise version of the code below to achieve this?

```
var myObject = {};
["a","b","c"].forEach(x => myObject[x] = true);
```

I feel like there's a succinct Lodash or ES6 way to do this but I can't think of it.

Comment: `["a","b","c"].reduce((a,v) => (a[v] = true) && a, {})`

Comment: `concise` is subjective and while it's interesting to see different approaches (I do like above reduce), I personally think asking `Is there a more concise version of the code` should be closed as **primarily opinion-based** `Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.`

Comment: Just define the thing in a function and put it in a module.. then... `import arrayToObject as $ from "./arrayToObject.js";`

`$(["a","b","c"], true);`

Cant get shorter than that...

Comment: @Nope fair point, it might be better content for the Code Review StackExchange. Keith that's a great one-liner, thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: We can use `Object.assign({}, ["a","b","c"])` to get result like: `{0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c"],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(k => ({ [k]: true })));
    
console.log(object);
```

Or with lodash and [`_.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/#set)

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c"],
    object = array.reduce((o, k) => _.set(o, k, true), {});

console.log(object);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My question may be correctly flagged as subjective but I've no idea why you're sitting on -1 points! Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myarray = ["a", "b", "c"];

var result = myarray.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item] = true;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Arguably no more concise than your version though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.zipObjects()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#zipObject) with the array of keys, and a 2nd array you [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) with the default value:

```js
const keys = ["a","b","c"];

const object = _.zipObject(keys, [...keys].fill(true));

console.log(object);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I created which can help you with this problem:

```js
  function arrToObj(arr, defaultVal) {
    let newObj = {};
    Object.keys(arr).forEach((item) => {
      newObj = { ...newObj, [item]: defaultVal };
    });
    return newObj;
  }
```

So now if you pass `arr=['a','b',c']` and `defaultVal=true` to this function

You will get `{'a':true, 'b':true, 'c':true}`