# Create new JSON string from array

Tags: javascript, json

Fairly new to JSON and I'm trying to get my head around conversions.  I have an array:

```
['Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3']
```

and I'm trying to stringify it so that it reads as

```
{"Role1": true, "Role2": true, "Role3": true}
```

So far I've tried assigning the original array to an object and the calling stringify but I can't figure out how to add the boolean value in the string.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `a.reduce((o, s) => { o[s] = true; return o }, {})` then JSON stringify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [More concise way of turning an array into an object with default values? (Lodash is available)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49305307/more-concise-way-of-turning-an-array-into-an-object-with-default-values-lodash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need as output?

```js
const arr = ['Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3']

const result = JSON.stringify(arr.reduce((a, n)=>{
    return {
        ...a,
        [n]: new Boolean(true).toString()    
    }
},{}))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: That would have the string `"true"`, not the *value* `true`. Unrelated, but `new Boolean(true).toString()` seems like a long way of writing `"true"`.

Comment: This should get me there, thank you!

Comment: @DaveNewton I wanted to make it dynamic. I just didn't initialize a variable. For example let bool = true and use new Boolean(bool). and I used toString, because I figured that's what OP needed.

Comment: `true.toString()` does what you'd expect; `new Boolean` is not needed. Regardless of the OP showing values, not strings, you could just use a variable--still dynamic.

Comment: The OP marked the answer as what he needed. and yeah. is not needed. Could have used true. I didn't imply it is needed.

Comment: :shrug: IMO putting it into an answer implies it's what's needed; YMMV.

Comment: I just pulled the toString method off, it got me where I needed to be.  Thank you to everyone

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create an intermediate reduce function to assign those values before converting to JSON.

```
const data = ['Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3']

const makeJson = () =>
  JSON.stringify(data.reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, [c]: true }), {}))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to combine [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = ['Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3']

const result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(s => [s, true]));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: I think I like this more than `reduce`; I forget about these helpers all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
let rolesArray = ['Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3']; 
let rolesObject = {};

// iterate over roles to fill an object 
rolesArray.forEach((role) => {
    rolesObject[role] = true; 
});

JSON.stringify(rolesObject) // Outputs the desired string
```

Or in a more concise way but less readable for a SO example :

```
JSON.stringify(rolesArray.reduce((o, s) => { o[s] = true; return o }, {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a preference for using the for-loop — still valid but other methods will be much short.

```js
var array = ["Role1", "Role2", "Role3"],
  json = {};
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  json[array[i]] = true;
}
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) so we can set the value to `true` without a second loop

Using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) to merge the objects

```js
const data = ['Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3'];
const obj = data.reduce((prev, cur) => ({ ...prev, [cur]: true }), {});

console.log(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```json
{
  "Role1": true,
  "Role2": true,
  "Role3": true
}
{"Role1":true,"Role2":true,"Role3":true}
```